# In jmeter how can I create a folder dynamically?

Tags: windows, jmeter, directory

A monthly PDF report is getting downloaded by the HTTP sampler. I'm passing the file path of this report in the prefix of 'Save responses to a file' listener which is a child of the HTTP sampler.

I'm passing the month name variable like ${month} in the file path, to create a folder dynamically as given below.
E:/Work/Monthly Productivity Report/${month}/MONTHLY_PRODUCTIVITY_REPORT_${month}_${__time(yyyyMMdd-hhmmss)}

But the script is throwing errors like unknown source or path not found. Is there any way where I can create new folder dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Add JSR223 Sampler, choose Language Java and put the code in script window:

```
String folder = vars.get("folder");

boolean success = (new File(folder)).mkdirs();

return success;
```

Answer (score 0):

For each test suite run:

JMeter always created a new testresult.csv and needs a blank new folder for report. So it is good to use .bat file to dynamically create the testresult.csv and report folder using this code.

Everytime you run .bat file, you will get new result.csv e.g. TestResults-Sat_09182021_160935_94.csv and new report folder e.g. Reports-Sat_09182021_160935_94

Add below code in Run.bat and open Run.bat:

```
set mydate=%date:/=% 
set mytime=%time::=% 
set mydatetime=%mydate:=_%_%mytime:.=_% 
jmeter -n -t "F:\WebsitePerformanceTest.jmx" -l "F:\TestResults-%mydatetime%.csv" -e -o "F:\Reports-%mydatetime%"
```

Enjoy !